# searching in bootstrap table

Tags: search, bootstrap-table

I have data-table containing files and folder, but when I search it only shows folder or files which present outside only. I'm not getting files or folder which are existing in folder. I'm using data-ajax for getting data from the database.
can we differentiate data which needs to be shown and which needs to use for search in bootstrap table?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the json as data input but not show in column/row.